# SetProperty to a class instance

Tags: php, class, field

I'm trying to set a property to a class instance dynamically. I've written the following:

```
class MyClass{
    public function setProp($prop){
        $this->{$prop}=$prop;
    }
}

$inst= new MyClass();
$vari='123';
$inst->setProp($vari);
echo $inst->vari;
```

I'm expected that after $inst->setProp($vari); method invokation the `$inst` `MyClass` instance has the `vari` field with the `123` value. But it's not true. How to fix this?

Comment: Your `setProp()` call tries to set property with name `123` and value `123`.

Comment: @hindmost Is it possible to set property with name `vari` and value `123`

Comment: `$vari` is simply the name of a variable ___outside___ of the call to setProp(), within set prop, there is only a __value__ `123` that is assigned to a local variable called `$prop`. setProp() doesn't even know that the value `123` came from a variable - it could equally have come from a constant, class constant, array element, hard-coded value, etc... it is simply a received value. It doesn't know about `$vari`, nor does it care

Comment: @MarkBaker Did you mean that expression passed as a function argument is resolving before the function is invoking itself?

Comment: The value passed to setProp() is the __value__ of the argument, whether you do `$vari='123';
$inst->setProp($vari);` or `$inst->setProp(123);` or `$vari='123'; function($t) { return $t; ) $inst->setProp(function($vari));`.... yes, it is resolved before the call to setProp()

Comment: If you want to do what you're trying to do, use the `__set()` magic method

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will set property with name `123` which is not valid property. If your code was

```
$vari='asd';
$inst->setProp($vari);
echo $inst->asd;
```

You would successfully create property with name `asd` and the same value

Because it's getting the variable value, but not its name.

(EDIT: My previous explanation was wrong)

---

You'd better has a second parameter with the property name.

```
class MyClass{
    public function setProp($name, $value){
        $this->{$name}=$value;
    }
}

$inst= new MyClass();
$vari='123';
$inst->setProp('vari',$vari);
echo $inst->vari;
```

Which ofcourse is like an overkill, if you do not have any logic around it (to be a valid setter).
Undefined properties will be set automatically

```
<?php
class MyClass{

}

$inst= new MyClass();
$inst->vari = 123;
echo $inst->vari;
```

P.S.: You will get into a trouble if you try it when the property exists and its private/protected

```
class MyClass{
    private $vari = 100;
    public function setProp($name, $value) {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
}

$inst= new MyClass();
$vari = 123;
$inst->setProp('vari', $vari);
echo $inst->vari;
```

Will result into `Fatal error: Cannot access private property MyClass::$vari`

To access private/protected/non-existent properties you can use magic method `__get()`. In order to write into then, you should use `__set()`.

```
class MyClass{
    private $vari = 100;
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}

$inst= new MyClass();
$inst->vari = 123;
echo $inst->vari;
```

However, if you don't have real reason to expose your inaccessible properties, it's not good idea to do it.